# What is the code in MySQL to go through the rows and delete some data?

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql, loops, duplicates

I'm doing a Query where I extract data from the BBDD called "tvp" with the titles ID, IDDriver, StatusActivation, DateCreation

when I want to subtract the "DateCreation" with "StatusActivation" 0 and the next record "StatusActivation" 1 to get the connection time, the "StatusActivation" (0 or 1) is repeated in a "DateCreation" in some rows

Example on Image (Link), sorry friends, I had to upload the image with link because the table in txt was never created.

https://ibb.co/r54PsBt

[image: example]

This is for MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE

Here, a fiddle: [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/h24LskgRDZCwTKGFHCfFwr/0)

```
SELECT 
  ID
 ,IDDriver
 ,StatusActivation
 ,DateCreation
   FROM 
    tb_logs
WHERE 
     DateCreation between '2019-01-01 00:00:00' and '2019-01-31 00:00:00';
```

I expect the output is that the "StatusActivation" 0 or 1, do not repeat in the "DateCreation" and "IDDriver" sequence

Comment: So you want one record with "0" and one with "1" for each ID and delete extra records?

Comment: You highlighted two records which are "duplicates" according to your definition.  _Which_ of the two records should be retained?  Are you sure that you want to actually delete the duplicates, or would a query/view just showing what you want be sufficient?

Comment: @Vasya - is exactly what has to happen but I want one record with "0" and one with "1" for each ID with each IDDriver

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - Yes I need the last record of the duplicates between "0" and "1" and between the dates where the "StatusActivatio" is duplicated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```sql
DELETE tb_logs WHERE StatusActivation=0 and ID Not in (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM tbl_logs  
WHERE StatusActivation=0 group by IDDriver )

DELETE tb_logs WHERE StatusActivation=1 and ID Not in (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM tbl_logs  
WHERE StatusActivation=1 group by IDDriver )
```

Comment: @FFrank: I made a small edit to ensure that records that only have one status/id combination are not deleted

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple question you ask.If your table contain `id` and some other unique columns then you can delete the data from table using specific id like i have done here.

```
DELETE FROM tb_logs WHERE ID IN (20,21);
```

I think your work is done from it.

Comment: thank you friend but that form would serve to delete only one record